# How to create a shortcut to add tags around selected text in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, markdown, shortcut

I'm using VS Code to edit markdown files and I'd like to create some new shortcuts, such as to highlight or underline selected texts. This can be achieved by surrounding selected text by `<mark>TEXT</mark>` or `<u>TEXT</u>`. And I want to create new shortcuts to add these tags around selected text, just like adding `**TEXT**` by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

I know how to create snippets but don't know how to write the command of these shorcuts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is very simple in VSCode because it has [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/) integrated into it.

You just select the text, open the command pallet (CTRL SHIFT P) and select `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation` and write your tag and it will automatically wrap the test in that tag. you can  also use Emmet class and tag syntax too.

Here is a demo:

[image: emmet demo]

You can set the keyboard shortcuts for this action too in VSCode. In the Keyboard Shorcut Screen you can search for Emmet wrap and change them.

[image: emmet shortcuts]

Comment: Is there a way to add a shortcut for "Wrap with Abbreviation" directly?

Comment: @DariodeJudicibus What do you mean directly? You can add a shortcut like Alt+Shift+W in the settings screen above and its invoked whenever you press that shortcut

Answer (score -1):

this is what i can recomment as a VS Code user.

please add this snippet,

```
"MYmARK": {
    "scope": "",
    "prefix": "my mark",
    "body": [
        "<mark>$1</mark>"
    ],
    "description": "mymark"
},
```

Then.
since you are selecting that text,
you can cut that and write "mymark" so the snippet will show. and hit enter

then paste your text and it will directly insert where $1 is located.